# Why is the req.cookies.session undefined? Firebase + Node + express

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, session-cookies

I'm trying to assign a generate a session cookie in exchange for the provided ID token. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) are the docs I'm following.

Here is my client side sign-in code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(user) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
            return sendToken(idToken);
        });
    })
    // .then(() => {
    //     return firebase.auth().signOut();
    // })
    .then(() => {
        window.location.assign('/member');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(errorMessage);
    });
```

My send sendToken() posts the idToken to the server:

```
function sendToken(idToken) {
console.log("Posting " + idToken);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = `token=${idToken}`;
xhr.open('POST', "/login", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve();
        } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
            reject("Invalid http return status");
        }
    }
   return xhr.send(params);
});
}
```

And at the server, I'm returning a session cookie:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
if (req.body.token) {
   const idToken = req.body.token.toString();
  // Set session expiration to 1 day.
   const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1 * 1000;
   return firebase.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn}).then((sessionCookie) => {
     const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
     res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
     res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
 });
}
return res.status(400).send("MISSING TOKEN");
});
```

I've also set up a middleware to verify the session cookie before the server serves the member info:

```
function authVerification(req, res, next){
 const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
 // Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to 
 detect
 // if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.
 return firebase.auth().verifySessionCookie(
 sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */).then((decodedClaims) => {
   console.log("decoded claims: " + decodedClaims);
   next();
   // serveContentForUser('/profile', req, res, decodedClaims);
 }).catch(error => {
   // Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
   res.send(error);
 });
}
```

But, when I try to get a member's page after signing in:

```
app.get("/member", authVerification, (req, res) => {
  res.send("member page");
});
```

I keep getting error from authVerification:

code: "auth/argument-error",
message: "Decoding Firebase session cookie failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents a session cookie. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies for details on how to retrieve a session cookie."

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution in the quickstart-nodejs repo.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/auth-sessions)

You have to add ***cookie-parser*** and ***body-parser***. Here is how I solved it with Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const next = require("next");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "next" } });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("Service account key"),
  databaseURL: "Path to database"
});

const server = express();
server.use(cors({ origin: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
// Support URL-encoded bodies.
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// Support cookie manipulation.
server.use(cookieParser());
// Attach CSRF token on each request.
server.use(attachCsrfToken('/', 'csrfToken', (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString()));


function attachCsrfToken(url, cookie, value) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url === url) {
      res.cookie(cookie, value);
    }
    next();
  }
}

server.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body && req.body.idToken) {
    const idToken = `${req.body.idToken}`;
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn }).then((sessionCookie) => {
      const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };
      res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ sessionCookie }));
    }, error => {
      res.status(401).send(error);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Token empty");
  }
});

server.post("/profile", (req, res) => {
  if (req.cookies && req.cookies.session) {
    const sessionCookie = `${req.cookies.session}`;
    admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(
      sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */).then((decodedClaims) => {
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ decodedClaims }));
    }).catch(error => {
      res.status(401).send(error);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Session empty");
  }
});

exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    if (!req.path) req.url = `/${request.url}`;
    return server(req, res);
  }

  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
});
```

Nothing special on the client side. You can use isomorphic-unfetch, axios or jQuery.

Comment: @francis, Thanks for sharing this. This definitely has helped me in understanding the whole concept in a better way. However. I'm still unable to set cookie. I've modified my code but still unable to set the browser cookie.

Comment: @francis - I want to clarify that I'm trying it on LocalHost and have set cookie options - secure: false. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you using on the client?

Comment: @francis, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it working. Followed the setup as it is in the GitHub repos. I'm not using any particular framework on the client. It's simple JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: @HimanshuPal Late response but just incase it helps anyone. You can't set cookies on localhost in most cases. I also believe firebase only allows the user to set one cookie called __session and clears the rest.