# req.cookies.session is undefined in Chrome

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, session-cookies

I'm implementing session login and session cookie verification with node.js + express + firebase.
My code below **works** in Firefox but not in Chorme. In Chrome, `req.cookies.session` is `undefined`

Here is my code:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.use(cookieParser());
```

```
async sessionLogin(req, res) {
        try {
            // Verify idToken
            const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
            var decodedToken = await this.authService.verifyIdToken(idToken);

            // Only process if the user just signed in in the last 5 minutes.
            if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedToken.auth_time > 5 * 60)
                throw { code: "auth/expired-token", message: "The provided token is expired."}

            // Set session expiration to 5 days.
            const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
            const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };

            var sessionCookie = await this.authService.createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn });

            res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
            res.json({ status: 'success' });
        } catch(err) {
            res.status(401).json(err);
        }
    }
```

```
    async checkSessionCookieMiddleware(req, res, next){
        const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
        console.log(sessionCookie);

        try {
            var decodedClaims = await this.authService.verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */);
            req.user = decodedClaims;
            next();
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Login is successful in any browser, then method `checkSessionCookieMiddleware` fails in Chrome as `req.cookies.session` is `undefined`.

Where's my mistake?

**SOLUTION:**

I found the solution.
I had to change
`const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };`
to
`const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: false /* to test in localhost */ };`

`scure: false` did the trick as I'm still serving from localhost.
Thanks also to @user2740650.

Comment: Is this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774148/why-is-the-req-cookies-session-undefined-firebase-node-express

Comment: I got inspired also from that answer but without success

Comment: I have nearly identical code that works fine in Chrome.  Are you sure that Chrome hasn't been configured to reject cookies?  Secondly, `secure: true` is used so you are using https in all cases, right?

Comment: ok, found the problem. I had to change the sessionCookie params to `const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: false /* to test in localhost */ };` as I'm serving from localhost

Comment: lol yep, missed it by 2 seconds.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks! I came to the same solution in the mean time thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to change

`const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };`

to

`const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: false /* to test in localhost */ };`

`scure: false` did the trick as I'm still serving from localhost. Thanks also to @user2740650.