# NodeJS + Google Login + Firebase Functions results in decoding firebase session cookie failed

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I require a Google Sign-In for a Firebase application, to get this done I used multiple sources:

- [auth-sessions](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/b2fcc5c36e1194dad3aeb4f176016deb281ca8a4/auth-sessions) provides a good out of the box example with NodeJS + Firebase + Google Login.
- [manage firebase session](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) provides a sample NodeJS functions (not entire working solution) to work with Firebase Functions.

### The problem:

When attempting to sign in into a Google account on production, the following error occurs when executing the code authenticate function below:

```
admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((decodedClaims) => {
        log("Decode success");

        // inbetween checks

        log("Successfully decoded and authenticated");
        next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        log("Error authenticating");          < ---- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    ...
    });
```

This error ONLY occurs when on production i.e. deployed to Firebase. When testing locally using firebase emulators emulating hosting and functions only (auth, firestore, database, etc are all production), login is successful. When deploying, the login fails with the error below.

**Error:**

Decoding Firebase session cookie failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents a session cookie. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies for details on how to retrieve a session cookie.

---

### More Details:

Below is a high-level overview of steps/actions performed

**Steps overview of actions performed**

```
1. Visit any page e.g. /login
2. Click sign in with Google, execute the popup provider (see [here][3])
2. 
    1. Sign in with Google account
    2. Send token to firebase functions for verification i.e. `POST /sessionLogin`
3. Receive response (assume 200 OK)
4. Redirect to authenticated URL
```

**The error is on the last step i.e. 4**

This error occurs after successfully creating a session using the sample `/sessionLogin` code found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#create_session_cookie) on firebase's site:

```
const auth = admin.auth();
auth.verifyIdToken(idToken).then(value => {
    debug("Token verified")
    return auth.createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})
        .then((sessionCookie) => {
            // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
            const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
            res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
            // res.json(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
            res.status(200).send("OK");
        }).catch((error) => {
            debug(error);
            res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
        });
}).catch(reason => {
    debug("Unable to verify token");
    debug(reason);
    res.status(401).send('INVALID TOKEN!');
});
```

The logs respond with a `Token verified` and a status 200 is sent to the client.

The client then redirects to an authenticated URL `/user/dashboard` which performs the authenticate check (see below) which fails and redirects back to `/login`:

```
const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    
    log("Authenticating");
    // source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions
    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
    // Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to detect
    // if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.

    return admin
        .auth()
        .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
        .then((decodedClaims) => {
            log("Decode success");

            // inbetween checks

            log("Successfully decoded and authenticated");
            next();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            log("Error authenticating");
            if(error.errorInfo && error.errorInfo.code && error.errorInfo.code === "auth/argument-error") {
                debug(error.errorInfo.message);
                res.redirect('/user/login');
                return;
            }
            debug(error);
            // Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
            req.flash("message", [{
                status: false,
                message: "Invalid session, please login again!"
            }])
            res.redirect('/user/login');
        });
};
```

which is middleware for the express app:

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://my-company-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "gs://my-company.appspot.com"
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser('0000-0000-0000-0000-0000'))
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
// Attach CSRF token on each request.
app.use(attachCsrfToken('/', 'csrfToken', (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString()));
app.use(session({
    secret: '0000-0000-0000-0000-0000',
    resave: false,
    name: '__session',
    store: new FirebaseStore({
        database: admin.database()
    }),
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(authenticate);

// routes

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

### Execution Logs:

> **1:12:02.796 PM** **app** Function execution started

> **1:12:02.910 PM** **app** Authenticating

> **1:12:02.910 PM** **app** Attempting to verify session cooking

> **1:12:02.910 PM** **app** Cookies: {}

> **1:12:02.911 PM** **app** Error authenticating

> **1:47:41.905 PM** **app** auth/argument-error

> **1:12:02.911 PM** **[app]** Decoding Firebase session cookie failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents a session
> cookie. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies
> for details on how to retrieve a session cookie.

> **1:12:02.937 PM** **[app]** Function execution took 141 ms, finished with status code: 302

---

**Update**

Call to backend for auth:

```
const postIdTokenToSessionLogin = (idToken, csrfToken) => {
    return axios({
        url: "/user/sessionLogin",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            idToken: idToken,
            csrfToken: csrfToken,
        },
    }).then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        if(value.status === 200) {
            window.location.assign("/user/dashboard");
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.error(reason);
        alert("Failed to login");
    });
}
```

Client side call:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(async value => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
            // const idToken = value.credential.idToken;
            const csrfToken = getCookie('_csrf');
            return postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken, csrfToken);
        }).catch(reason => {
            console.error("Failed to get current user token");
            alert(reason.message);
        });
    })/*.then(value => {
    window.location.assign("/user/dashboard")
})*/.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Failed to sign in with Google");
    alert(error.message);
});
```

---

**Update 2:**

Updated client-side axios request with the following, also added extra `req.cookies` logging

```
return axios({
    url: "/user/sessionLogin",
    method: "POST",
    withCredentials: true,
    data: {
        idToken: idToken,
        csrfToken: csrfToken,
    },
})
```

**Extra logging:**

> **4:43:23.493 PM app** Function execution started

> **4:43:23.501 PM app** Authenticating

> **4:43:23.501 PM app** Creating session

> **4:43:23.502 PM app** /sessionLogin Cookies: {"csrfToken":"19888568527706150","session":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InRCME0yQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3Nlc3Npb24uZmlyZWJ..."}

> **4:43:23.503 PM app** Token verified

> **4:43:23.503 PM app** {"name":redacted ,"picture":"","iss":"","aud":"",...}

> **4:43:23.503 PM app** ==============

> **4:43:23.503 PM app** /sessionLogin#verifyIdToken Cookies: {"csrfToken":"19888568527706150","session":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InRCME0yQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3Nlc3Npb24uZmlyZWJ..."}

> **4:43:23.634 PM app** /sessionLogin#createSessionCookie Cookies: {"csrfToken":"19888568527706150","session":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InRCME0yQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3Nlc3N..."}

> **4:43:23.634 PM app** Cookie:

> **4:43:23.634 PM app** "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InRCME0yQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3Nlc3Npb24uZmlyZWJhc2UuZ29vZ..."

> **4:43:23.634 PM app** ==============

> **4:43:23.643 PM app** [0mPOST /user/sessionLogin [32m200[0m 139.036 ms - 2[0m

> **4:43:23.643 PM app** Function execution took 150 ms, finished with status code: 200

> **4:43:24.131 PM app** Function execution started

> **4:43:24.153 PM app** Authenticating

> **4:43:24.153 PM app** Attempting to verify session cooking

> **4:43:24.153 PM app** Cookies: {}

---

**Update 3**

Rewrites enabled API & NodeJS access exactly as shown in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site": "my-company-admin-portal",
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When the function is deployed (or making calls to your server), from where are you calling function? Localhost or a live domain? I was able to replicate the issue but when calling the function from localhost.

Comment: @Dharmaraj it works correctly on local with emulators, but fails on live.

Comment: @Dharmaraj with this, it works correctly `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --only functions,hosting,firestore,database,storage` on local, but when deployed on live it doesn't

Comment: I mean, the function is deployed to live but from which domain (of webapp) do you make the call? Any live domain or localhost?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I call from e.g. `https://my-company-admin-portal.web.app/user/login`

Comment: @Dharmaraj do you have a sample project of a deployed example that works? If so, is it possible you can provide this example with sensitive info, etc omitted ofc?

Answer (score 2):

`sessionCookie` is undefined as in the code provided in the question.

```js
// Authenticate middleware right now
const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {

  log("Authenticating");
  // No sessionCookie declared
  return admin
        .auth()
        .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
  // undefined passed here   ^^^
}
```

You must pass the cookie that you set after using `createSessionCookie` in `verifySessionCookie` method as shown below:

```js
// updated authenticate middleware
const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    log("Authenticating");

    // Read the value of cookie here
    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session

    // Return unauthorized error if cookie is absent
    if (!sessionCookie) return res.sendStatus(401)

    const decodedClaims = await admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true)

    // cookie verified, continue 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return res.send("An error occurred")
  }
}
```

Comment: please see update of `authenticate` function

Comment: Update: `const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';` I had omitted this, my apologies. This was present, but always ended up as being null or undefined which seems to be the root of my problem.

Comment: @CybeX I'll `console.log(req.cookies)` and check if session cookie is present. Apart from that, can you also share the fetch request's code that you make from frontend?

Comment: @Dharmarag so you can find the `req.cookies` in the execution logs. When authenticating, I log the cookies, which is `{}`. I will see what the `req.cookies` is at every interaction and update the post.

Comment: @CybeX please share the axios/fetch request that you are making from frontend. I'd like to confirm if credentials are included?

Comment: @CybeX can you add `withCredentials: true` in your axios request? Actually even in the request where you set the cookie. [Axios docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#:~:text=withCredentials%3A%20false)

Comment: see update 2, I added some extra context to `req.cookies`

Comment: @CybeX it does seem like session cookie can be read now and `req.cookies` is no more `{}`. You need to set `withCredentials: true` in all requests so cookies are included. The axios request to get a session cookie must have that to true as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236689/discussion-between-cybex-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774148/why-is-the-req-cookies-session-undefined-firebase-node-express) in which they have a similar issue.

In summary, if you check the [quickstart-nodejs](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/auth-sessions) repository you have to add the `cookie-parser` and `body-parser`. Here is the example that they provide in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800660/9330208):

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const next = require("next");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "next" } });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("Service account key"),
  databaseURL: "Path to database"
});

const server = express();
server.use(cors({ origin: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
// Support URL-encoded bodies.
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// Support cookie manipulation.
server.use(cookieParser());
// Attach CSRF token on each request.
server.use(attachCsrfToken('/', 'csrfToken', (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString()));


function attachCsrfToken(url, cookie, value) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url === url) {
      res.cookie(cookie, value);
    }
    next();
  }
}

server.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body && req.body.idToken) {
    const idToken = `${req.body.idToken}`;
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn }).then((sessionCookie) => {
      const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };
      res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ sessionCookie }));
    }, error => {
      res.status(401).send(error);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Token empty");
  }
});

server.post("/profile", (req, res) => {
  if (req.cookies && req.cookies.session) {
    const sessionCookie = `${req.cookies.session}`;
    admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(
      sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */).then((decodedClaims) => {
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ decodedClaims }));
    }).catch(error => {
      res.status(401).send(error);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Session empty");
  }
});

exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    if (!req.path) req.url = `/${request.url}`;
    return server(req, res);
  }

  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting cloud function in firebase hosting, '__session' is the only key we can use.

Also set Cache-Control as private

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
```

For more detail, see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935288/11079057)